# Conflicting log4j configuration files in referenced java projects using eclipse. No log output from Spring as a result

Tags: eclipse, spring, log4j

I have two projects in eclipse - a Java project (let's call it Project A) and a Dynamic Web Project (Project B). Both projects use log4j and both have their own configuration files(as it is now, Project A uses a log4j.properties file and Project B a log4j.xml file). I require Project A to call code from Project B, so in Project A's build path, Project B is added as a required project. This seems to confuse log4j, as it loads it's configuration from Project B's log4j.xml file instead of Project A's log4j.properties. To combat this, I added the line "-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties" in my launch configuration, which seems to work. Indeed, the formatting of the logger output is now as described in Project A's log4j.properties.

Both projects also use spring for database connections. The problem I am faced with now is that all logging output from spring seems to be missing. If I remove Project B from Project A's build path the problem goes away and I see the log output from Spring in the console. Is there something inherently wrong with my approach here? If not, any suggestions to make Spring's log output appear in the console while keeping Project B in Project A's build path?

Sorry for the long winded explanation. Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have have the log4j config file for Project B in the classpath. In both projects, make sure the config file is *not* in the classpath and use the -Dlog4j.configuration technique instead.

Usually, for things like this I try not to have multiple log4j files. If both projects have standalone Java main()s, then you may want to consider having a 'common' project for both projects that contains common configuration files like log4j.